Nietzsche about philosophical Realism
What did Nietzsche think about philosophical Realism? As I understand that he was a perspectivist.
Does that imply that he thought that there are absolute truths, but we can not interact with them because we are physical beings and restrained by our perceptions or that he thought that there are no absolute truths per se?

To help answer, what do you think about philosophical Realism? I'm not a scholar, but it is possible to have views that are not just an either / or of some named stance. Mr. Nietzsche might have seen it in a way we cannot understand, or put in words, or maybe it changed over time. That's why one's own view is so crucial to what we understand (see what I did there? :-) ).

@ScottRowe Hi, do you mean: "What is my definition of philosophical Realism" or "What is my personal opinion on philosophical Realism"?

Well, I hope your definition is ok already, and one's opinion never matters when determining the truth. So, what does it seem in terms of truth (no, too direct...) er, usefulness? How does it help or hinder? Sneak up on it. Well, time for breakfast.

The issue is not simple...
See e.g. Maudemarie Clark, Nietzsche on Truth and Philosophy (Cambridge UP, 1991), page 1:

Nietzsche's position on truth seems to amount to a denial that any human beliefs is, or could be, true. He proclaims, for example, that "truths are illusions we have forgotten are illusions. [Twilight of the Idols (1889)]"

And see page 3, for the discussion about the seemingly self-contradiciton in Nietzsche: "if it is supposed to be true that there is no truth, then there is apparently a truth after all".
See also Nietzsche's Perspectivism:

Nietzsche makes perspectivist claims not only concerning the side of the cognitive subject, but also about the side of the truth, or reality, we aim to know. His views on this topic have been highly controversial, with some scholars emphasizing Nietzsche’s apparent denials of truth (either skeptical denials that any truth is ever knowable, or more radical claims that the very idea of truth is somehow incoherent), and others highlighting his own frequent and routine claims for the truth of his own views


Zap! Nonduality! I'll have to take off my Nietzsche mask at parties now.

Hm, that all kind of smells like the Liar's paradox equivalence of the absolute truth paradox.

If there is a contradiction that contradiction is constructed by following some logic, but what makes us so sure that we can depend on logic to lead us to the correct answers.

I know that sounds radical, I am not saying that logic is bad, but it is build on some axioms and maybe we can build some philosophy that is not bound by that.

Thank you for the references.

@User198 consider looking in to Nonduality. (Not the philosophical position with that name, the real thing.)

@ScottRowe I don't follow. I found "Nondualism - includes a number of philosophical and spiritual traditions that emphasize the absence of fundamental duality or separation in existence..." Do you mean that or something else?

@User198 yes, just avoid philosophers and Alan Watts.

Nietzsche does not think there is absolute truth.

To the extent to which knowledge has any sense at all, the world is
knowable: but it may be interpreted differently, it has not one
sense behind it, but hundreds of senses.—"Perspectivity."
WM 481


Plato, for instance, when he persuaded himself that "the good," as he
wanted it, was not Plato's good, but "the good in itself," the eternal
treasure which a certain man of the name of Plato had chanced to find
on his way!
WM 972


A "thing-in-itself" is just as absurd as a "sense-in-itself," a
"meaning-in-itself." There is no such thing as a
"fact-in-itself," for a meaning must always be given to it before it
can become a fact.
WM 556

